# What is the difference between $(command) and `command` in shell programming?

Tags: bash, shell, ksh, sh

To store the output of a command as a variable in sh/ksh/bash, you can do either

```
var=$(command)
```

or

```
var=`command`
```

What's the difference if any between the two methods?

Comment: Please see [BashFAQ/082](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082).

Comment: You will find the nested issue detailed in the Git Coding Guideline: see [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24592916/6309).

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/126927

Answer (score 332, accepted):

The backticks/gravemarks have been deprecated in favor of `$()` for command substitution because `$()` can easily nest within itself as in `$(echo foo$(echo bar))`.  There are other differences such as how backslashes are parsed in the backtick/gravemark version, etc.

See [**BashFAQ/082**](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082) for several reasons to always prefer the $(...) syntax.

Also see the [**POSIX**](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/xrat/V4_xcu_chap02.html#tag_23_02_06_03) spec for detailed information on the various differences.

Comment: Good link, but that text doesn't _deprecate_ backquotes in favour of `$(...)` – it just notes them as alternatives.

Comment: @NormanGray POSIX may not say the word *deprecated* but it does say `"the backquoted variety of command substitution is not recommended"` which is just a long winded way of saying deprecated IMHO

Comment: POSIX did not deprecate backticks,but rather added `$(...)` as an alternative method. There is no known implementation bug with backticks, but there are many known implementation bugs with `$(...) `. So for portability issues it is recommended to use backticks for non-nested calls. `$(...)` needs a recursive parser but this was not used with ksh86 that introduced the feature. Check http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/cmd-subst/  for a list of correct implementations. A conforming shell needs to support all cases except case D.2.

Comment: There are other things in POSIX that need to be seen as `deprecated`, e.g. the use of `waitpid()` that prevents you from from seeing the full 32 bits from the `exit()` parameter, but all shells except the recent Bourne Shell still use `waitpid()` instead of the `waitid()` call that is now available since 26 years.

Comment: The link in the answer hints that there are some differences between the backticks and `$()`, which is more explained [in this part of the documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_03). The differences is not only about nesting.

Comment: Is the eval bash specific?  It will not start a subshell as opposed to starting a subshell by $(cmd) or \`cmd\`

Comment: @KeminZhou... huh? Eval is not bash-specific, but I don't see what it has to do with any of this. If you want to run `cmd` in your current shell, the easiest way to do that is just `cmd`, not `eval cmd`.

Comment: What about compatibility - is the `$()` syntax supported by all commonly used shells aside from Bash (e.g. csh, zsh, fish)? It might be useful to add a note about it to the answer.

Comment: @szx yes. That is what posix implies

Answer (score 43):

They behave the same. The difference is syntactical: it's easier to nest `$()` than ``` `` ```:

```
listing=$(ls -l $(cat filenames.txt))
```

vs.

```
listing=`ls -l \`cat filenames.txt\``
```

Comment: `echo $(echo \$abc)` is not the same as ``echo `echo \$abc`‍`` - Differences also exist for ``$(echo \`)`` and  ``$(echo \\)``

Comment: Another difference is: `echo foo \`#comment\`` vs `echo foo $(#comment)`. The second one doesn't work. (Used for commenting in a multi-line command.)

Answer (score 31):

July 2014: The [commit f25f5e6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f25f5e61a7c1a22dd85413d61db639e7c01268f4) (by [Elia Pinto (`devzero2000`)](https://github.com/devzero2000), April 2014, Git 2.0) adds to the nesting issue:

> The backquoted form is the traditional method for command substitution, and is supported by POSIX.
>   **However, all but the simplest uses become complicated quickly.
>
>   In particular, embedded command substitutions and/or the use of double quotes require
>   careful escaping with the backslash character**.

That is why the [git/Documentation/CodingGuidelines](https://github.com/git/git/blob/6f92e5ff3cdc813de8ef5327fd4bad492fb7d6c9/Documentation/CodingGuidelines#L72-L74)  mentions:

> We prefer `$( ... )` for command substitution; **unlike ``, it  properly nests**.
>   It should have been the way Bourne spelled it from day one, but unfortunately isn't.

[thiton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/847601/thiton) [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8941381/what-is-the-difference-between-backticks-and-in-bash-script#comment11202254_8941461):

> That is why ``` `echo `foo`` ```  won't work in general because of the inherent ambiguity because each ``` `` ```can be opening or closing.
>   It might work for special cases due to luck or special features.

---

Update January 2016: Git 2.8 (March 2016) gets rid of backticks entirely.

See [commit ec1b763](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ec1b763d05bb03d8741c1363d7acf4ccb7153f6d), [commit 9c10377](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9c1037751c0204c494b1ed49e8c1d94429ea78b1), [commit c7b793a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c7b793a17d92350632c51a24e06b6a3dc4a93c2b), [commit 80a6b3f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/80a6b3f0d54d0df6c6994df5486433bf0b9a54c0), [commit 9375dcf](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9375dcf3b9bb1e462e28d5017165e1c7fa741c77), [commit e74ef60](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e74ef604974192712c38f77cd751b00ad36e1378), [commit 27fe43e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/27fe43e869f4ee8865beeedf6f2bbbab07cf0c7c), [commit 2525c51](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2525c5170f1088dac0aeb18444041f9fff04761a), [commit becd67f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/becd67fd281fa0efdf8f6346f311954a237dc991), [commit a5c98ac](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a5c98acec6ad8e8c397b1001621a4edfacc98516), [commit 8c311f9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8c311f96a5a089d2f35654e9af7c44377a27839b), [commit 57da049](https://github.com/git/git/commit/57da04965d56c7d7da6a00c3fb6fc3981cf0ba9a), [commit 1d9e86f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1d9e86f80d2ede6829c57ef4b22e4dd8b162cc7e), [commit 78ba28d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/78ba28d84b5be8cbb1d5d5e7d65b5522739ad5ce), [commit efa639f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/efa639fe6b850de699b675bf3e9c4b35f54f54bc), [commit 1be2fa0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1be2fa02b5ac97346e6745c767c559ee363ff378), [commit 38e9476](https://github.com/git/git/commit/38e947660b2bb09e035f91b682b7011c2808052e), [commit 8823d2f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8823d2fa792efbc89d3ab1392a4b064e8fbd6705), [commit 32858a0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/32858a01506b22963cfd5f8c8db95486f26133af), [commit cd914d8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/cd914d8090d64c8df1b0c45327de7dacdf370a09) (12 Jan 2016) by [Elia Pinto (`devzero2000`)](https://github.com/devzero2000).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit e572fef](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e572fef9d459497de2bd719747d5625a27c9b41d), 22 Jan 2016)</sup>

From Git 2.8 onwards, it is all `$(...)`, no more `` `...` ``.

Comment: `$()` is also POSIX-specified -- a quote that describes backticks as "POSIX-supported" in such a way to imply that this is unique to them is misleading. It's only (1970s-era) pre-POSIX Bourne where backticks are the only supported syntax.

Answer (score 29):

When the older back-tick form is used, backslash retains its literal meaning except when followed by $, `, or \. The first back-tick not preceded by a backslash terminates the command substitution.

When using the newer `$(command)` form, all characters between the parentheses make up the command; none are treated specially.

Both forms can be nested, but the back-tick variety requires the following form.

```
`echo \`foo\``
```

As opposed to:

```
$(echo $(foo))
```

Comment: Minor correction, both the backtick version and the `$()` version are POSIX compliant.

Answer (score 6):

There is little difference, except for what unescaped characters you can use inside of the command. You can even put **`...`** commands inside **$(...)** ones (and vice versa) for a more complicated two-level-deep command substitution.

There is a slightly different interpretation of the backslash character/operator. Among other things, when nesting **`...`** substitution commands, you must escape the inner **`** characters with **\,** whereas with **$()** substition it understands the nesting automatically.

Answer (score 2):

"What's the difference if any between the two methods?"

Make attention to this behaviour:

```
A="A_VARIABLE"
echo "$(echo "\$A")"
echo "`echo "\$A"`"
```

You will get these results:

```
$A
A_VARIABLE
```

Comment: `echo "$(echo "\$A")"` should be compared with `echo "\`echo \"\$A\"\`"`. The output is the same.

Comment: I tried your notation now, still output is $A and A_VARIABLE.

Comment: Difference is that $() don't translating escaped (\$A) variables and ` ` translating. Way is to double escape variable inside ` ` - `\\$A`.
Conclusion for this is that you can't simply replace ` ` with $( ). Is need to check it inside for escape characters.
(GNU bash, version 4.2.46(2)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu))

Answer (score 0):

One novel difference between backticks and the newer preferred POSIX syntax for command substitution is in how comments are handled.  A hash character within backticks creates a comment that ends at the second backtick character, effectively creating a way to have mid-line comments.

```sh
$ echo "Goodbye` # Cruel` World"
Goodbye World
```

Using the newer preferred syntax, the comment continues to the end of the line, so the command would have to be split across two lines:

```sh
$ echo "Goodbye$( # Cruel
> ) World"
Goodbye World
```

If you tried to type it into a console on a single line, your terminal would just wrap:

```sh
$ echo "Goodbye$( # Cruel) World"
>
```

But, you can force it to one line by passing the command to `sh -c`.  Then you'll see that it results in a syntax error:

```sh
$ sh -c 'echo "Goodbye$( # Cruel) World"'
sh: 1: Syntax error: end of file unexpected (expecting ")")
```