# How to checkout in Git by date?

Tags: git, git-checkout

I am working on a regression in the source code.  I'd like to tell Git: "checkout the source based on a parameterized date/time". Is this possible?

I also have staged changes in my current view that I don't want to lose.  Ideally, I would like to toggle back and forth between the current source, and some version I'm interested in based on a previous date.

Comment: Just in case you don't know about it, [git bisect](http://kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-bisect.html) is pretty great for finding regressions. I would say, use the {1 year ago} syntax like Andy said, to find a known-good commit, then use that as your initial `git bisect good` point.

Comment: I feel like this is a good use case for `tags`.

Answer (score 484, accepted):

#### To keep your current changes

You can keep your work stashed away, without commiting it, with `git stash`. You
would than use `git stash pop` to get it back. Or you can (as *carleeto* said) `git commit` it to a separate branch.

#### Checkout by date using rev-parse

You can checkout a commit by a specific date using `rev-parse` like this:

```
git checkout 'master@{1979-02-26 18:30:00}'
```

More details on the available options can be found in the [`git-rev-parse`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-rev-parse).

*As noted in the comments this method uses the reflog to find the commit in your history. By default these entries [expire after 90 days](http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-gc). Although the syntax for using the reflog is less verbose you can only go back 90 days.*

#### Checkout out by date using rev-list

The other option, which doesn't use the reflog, is to use `rev-list` to get the commit at a particular point in time with:

```
git checkout `git rev-list -n 1 --first-parent --before="2009-07-27 13:37" master`
```

Note the **--first-parent** if you want only your history and not versions brought in by a merge. That's what you usually want.

Comment: @Rocky Can you give us more details Rocky?  What are you entering on the command line and why do you say it's not working?  Are you getting an error message?

Comment: here is the message: git co master@{2011-11-11}
warning: Log for 'master' only goes back to Tue, 13 Dec 2011 02:19:31 +0000.

Comment: another: git co master@{2 days ago}
error: pathspec 'master@{2' did not match any file(s) known to git.
error: pathspec 'days' did not match any file(s) known to git.
error: pathspec 'ago}' did not match any file(s) known to git.

Comment: @Rocky: The problem is that the parameter needs to be enclosed in quotes, else bash separates the arguments at spaces. Try `git co 'master@{2 days ago}'`.

Comment: Note: depending on how far back you go, this may not work because it uses the reflog (which expires after some time). You will see 'warning: Log for 'master' only goes back to...'. 
Rocky's solution will work always.
git checkout `git rev-list -n 1 --before="2009-07-27 13:37" master`

Comment: Yes. See the link posted by Carleeto and Rocky.

Comment: I edited your answer because backticks are deprecated and difficult to read. Subshells `$(...)` are preferred.

Comment: Note that the rev-list solution won't work as expected when merges are involved. In particular, it can choose one of the commits on any of the branches being merged, even though the commit in question was not actually on master at the time.

Comment: Note that this uses the commit's date, which is typically fine.  See below for an answer that uses the author date.

Comment: Just an FYI. "master" is a local branch. If its not up to date you may not get the files you expect. Instead you may want to use 'origin/master'

Comment: @Andy Happy 40th birthday, Andy!  (assuming that's what 1979-02-26 meant :))

Comment: Seems like the branch and date are optional, so this also works if you only care about the date: `git checkout '@{1979-02-26}'`

Comment: I just wasted a lot of time because this solution gives me the top of the master branch!

Answer (score 175):

Andy's solution does not work for me. Here I found another way:

```sh
git checkout `git rev-list -n 1 --before="2009-07-27 13:37" master`
```

[Git: checkout by date](http://web.archive.org/web/20170303015800/http://bramschoenmakers.nl/en/node/645)

Comment: When I execute above command I get `error: unknown switch \`n'` any ideas how to get around this?

Comment: @Tim Run it in two parts, first run the `git rev-list` and only after that run the `git checkout` with the commit you get from the first command.

Comment: Instead of `-n 1` you should use `--max-count=1`

Comment: You should explain what the need for the options are. Why -n 1? What is the difference to not passing it?

Comment: This does not work on GIT for Windows at all! (GIT version 2.30.1). 
It looks like rev-list command always ignoring any of such input cmdline options. :-\

Answer (score 21):

Looks like you need something along the lines of this:
[Git checkout based on date](http://bramschoenmakers.nl/en/node/645)

In other words, you use `rev-list` to find the commit and then use checkout to
actually get it.

If you don't want to lose your staged changes, the easiest thing would be to
create a new branch and commit them to that branch. You can always switch back
and forth between branches.

Edit: The link is down, so here's the command:

```
git checkout `git rev-list -n 1 --before="2009-07-27 13:37" master`
```

Comment: Great link! So `git checkout branch@{date}` stops working when the reflog expires, but you can use `git checkout \`git rev-list -n 1 --before="2009-07-27 13:37" master\``.

Answer (score 15):

To those who prefer a pipe to command substitution

```
git rev-list -n1 --before=2013-7-4 master | xargs git checkout
```

Answer (score 13):

In my case the `-n 1` option doesn't work. On Windows I've found that the following sequence of commands works fine:

```
git rev-list -1 --before="2012-01-15 12:00" master
```

This returns the appropriate commit's SHA for the given date, and then:

```
git checkout SHA
```

Answer (score 11):

Reminder, since Git 2.23 (Aug. 2019)

- switch to a new branch from a past commit by date:

  ```
  git switch -c newBranch $(git rev-list -n1 --before=yyyy-mm-dd main)
  ```
- restore a file at a past date in the current working tree

  ```
  git restore -SW -s $(git rev-list -n1 --before=yyyy-mm-dd main) -- path/to/file
  ```

Do not use the [old, obsolete and confusing `git checkout` command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57066202/6309) in 2021/2022:  [`git switch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-switch) and [`git restore`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-restore) describe exactly what they are doing (working with only branches for `git switch`, and only with files for `git restore`)

Do not use ``: [prefer the more modern `$(command substitution)` syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24592916/6309) over obsolescent backtick syntax.

Answer (score 6):

To create a new branch from the checkout, use -b option with new branch name.

```
git checkout -b 19July2021 `git rev-list -n1 --before=2021-7-19 master`
```

You can avoid `git switch`, when you are in 'detached HEAD' state

Answer (score 5):

The `git rev-parse` solution proposed by @Andy works fine if the date you're interested is the *commit's date*.  If however you want to checkout based on the *author's date*, `rev-parse` won't work, because it doesn't offer an option to use that date for selecting the commits.  Instead, you can use the following.

```
git checkout $(
  git log --reverse --author-date-order --pretty=format:'%ai %H' master |
  awk '{hash = $4} $1 >= "2016-04-12" {print hash; exit 0 }
)
```

(If you also want to specify the time use `$1 >= "2016-04-12" && $2 >= "11:37"` in the *awk* predicate.)

Answer (score 3):

Going further with the `rev-list` option, if you want to find the most recent merge commit from your master branch into your production branch (as a purely hypothetical example):

```sh
git checkout `git rev-list -n 1 --merges --first-parent --before="2012-01-01" production`
```

I needed to find the code that was on the production servers as of a given date. This found it for me.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to be able to return to the precise version of the repository at the time you do a build it is best to tag the commit from which you make the build.

The other answers provide techniques to return the repository to the most recent commit in a branch as of a certain time-- but they might not always suffice. For example, if you build from a branch, and later delete the branch, or build from a branch that is later rebased, the commit you built from can become "unreachable" in git from any current branch. Unreachable objects in git may eventually be removed when the repository is compacted.

Putting a tag on the commit means it never becomes unreachable, no matter what you do with branches afterwards (barring removing the tag).

Comment: Although this does not give me the answer I look for, it does deserve a good mention for pointing out an aspect not mentioned so far. This could be the source of problems that prevent you from reaching the right version.

Answer (score 3):

You only need a little change if you hit the limit of reflog (the date you cloned the repo or 90 days a go of history it seems from other notes)

```
git checkout `git rev-list -1 --before="Jan 17 2020" HEAD`
```

And you can also use

```
git checkout `git rev-list -1 --before="Jan 17 2020 8:06 UTC-8" HEAD`
```

it will checkout the previous commit related to the date or the date-time you enter, see that you can use modifiers for the date, I guess if you dont use UTC+-N it just uses UTC time.

> See that I only changed master to HEAD, it seems to work even if you dont have reflog to the date you want to check!!!

Answer (score 2):

Here's an alias version that I use to checkout by relative time:

```
[alias]
    parsedate = "!set -x ;arg1=\"$1\" && shift && which gdate &> /dev/null && gdate -d \"$arg1\" || date -d \"$arg1\""
    codate = "!d=\"$(git parsedate \"$1\")\" && shift && git checkout \"$(git rev-list -n1 --first-parent --before=\"$d\" HEAD)\""
```

This allows you to checkout your changes from 2 months ago into a new branch named `test` using the following command:

```sh
git codate '2 months ago' -b test
```

This won't work on a shallow clone so unshallow it first with:

```sh
git fetch --unshallow
```

If you get an unshallow error, you might find help from the excellent answer at [git fatal: error in object: unshallow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63879454/4466440)

Requires GNU coreutils and works on Linux and macOS using brew.

Install on macos using `brew install coreutils`.

Answer (score 1):

```
git rev-list -n 1 --before="2009-07-27 13:37" origin/master
```

take the printed string (for instance XXXX) and do:

```
git checkout XXXX
```

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate of @bartoszkp answer? just adding the reference to origin, should be a comment on the other answer...

Comment: yes, in fact almost, just clearifing what to copy for who does not know what SHA is (like me), in my case that text was not clear and this is my code after founding the solution, not copied, in fact you can see the options are sligtly different too

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check out a single file as of a specific date, you can pass the filepath to both commands.

```
git checkout `git rev-list -n 1 --before="2009-07-27 13:37" master FILEPATH` FILEPATH
```