# Get snapshot of a git repo on a particular date

Tags: git, git-log, git-checkout

Say I have a repo with multiple banches.

Is it possible to get the repo snapshot of some particular date/time using usual git foo?
(We currently have code dumps every day, and I am thinking of ways to remove that)

(Assuming no branches are permanently deleted, and the git commit history hasn't been played with)

Edit: Interim branch merges are possible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Beware of the `@{<date>}`, based on the reflog (meaning, limited by default to 90 days).
See "[Specifying Revisions](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-parse#_specifying_revisions)" in [`git rev-parse`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-parse).

"[git checkout by date](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8514828/6309)" suggests another method:

```
git checkout `git rev-list -n 1 --before="2013-09-25 5:00" master`
```

Note [this warning though](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12215316/6309):

> `rev-list` won't work if you have any branches merged.
>   For example: I wanted to go back on `V5` branch but ended up in `V4.2` branch.

A more robust way would to add `--first-parent`:

```
git checkout `git rev-list -n 1 --first-parent --before="2013-09-25 5:00" master`
```