# How do I checkout the snapshot of the master branch from git at a given date/time?

Tags: git, git-branch

If a commit was made in other branches and merged into `master` after the given date/time, the changes in that commit should not appear in the snapshot, even though the commit was made before the given date/time

Option 2 in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6990682/1305362) doesn't do the job I need, as it simply sorts the commits chronologically and return the latest revision before the given date/time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can still start with that answer (which I'll repeat here, slightly modified, since I'm about to pick it apart):

> ```
> git checkout `git rev-list -n 1 --before="yesterday" master`
> ```

The problem you want to avoid is that `git rev-list` finds *all* commits that are reachable from the tip of branch `master`, including other branches that were merged into `master`, e.g.:

```
...-A--C---E   <-- master
   /      /
...--B---D     <-- develop
```

Let's say that the commit you would like to find is the one labeled `C`, but `D` is later than `C` (while still being old enough to be picked up by the `--before` option).  The `git rev-list` finds all commits reachable from `E` (the tip of branch `master`) whose date-stamp<sup>1</sup> is early enough.  The `-n 1` causes it to stop as soon as it finds one: without this, it would list first commit `D`, then commit `C`, then even more commits (`B`, then `A`, etc).

However, there are more options you can pass to `git rev-list`.  For instance, `--topo-order` causes the commits to come out in a "topologically sorted" order: you'd get `D`, then `B`, then `C`, then `A`.  Not quite what we wanted either, but it shows that `git rev-list` is a complicated little beastie. :-)

What we really need is a way to tell `git rev-list` that it should not go down the path of commits that were *merged into* master from other branches.  It turns out there are two ways to do this, with two different flaws.

#### using `--first-parent`

The first and simplest way is to use `--first-parent` (simply add this to the arguments to `git rev-list`).  In this case, whenever `git rev-list` hits a fork while working backwards—e.g., from `E` to both `C` and `D`—this instructs it to follow only the *first* parent.  When this works, it works because every `git merge` commit specifically records the *current* branch as the first parent, and any merged-in commits/branches as second parents (or even third, fourth, etc., parents, in the case of an "octopus merge").

This *fails* when there's a merge commit on your branch caused by someone using, e.g., `git pull` to merge their work into a branch line.  Remember that `git pull` is just `git fetch` followed by `git merge`, so someone working on branch `branch` makes their private commit `K`, someone else also working on branch makes their private commit `L`, the person who made `L` pushes first, and the person who made `K` pushes but gets "not a fast forward" so `pull`s and then `push`es.  Their `pull` merges their `K` with commit `L`:

```
...-o--K---M   <-- branch
     \    /
      --L-     <-- origin/branch
```

and then they `push` successfully so that `origin/branch` now points to merge commit `M`:

```
...-o--K---M   <-- branch, origin/branch
     \    /
      --L-
```

The first parent of merge `M` is `K`; `L`, which was made on `branch` by *someone else*, is the second parent.  The `--first-parent` option to `git rev-list` will skip over commit `L` because it was merged in (by whoever made and pushed `K`).

If you have a strict policy of rebasing instead of merging, this situation does not arise in the first place, so you can ignore it.  If not, you can either live with the flaw (of skipping these commits) or try the second option.

#### using `--not ...`

Another way to exclude branches like `develop` is, well, to exclude branches like `develop`.  You want all commits that are reachable from `master`, but are *not* reachable by starting from the tip of any other branch.

First, you need a list of all branches, or at least all branches to discard.  Let's get a complete list of all branches (and only branches), except for `master` itself:

```
git for-each-ref --format='%(refname:short)' refs/heads | grep -v '^master$'
```

Next, you simply ask git for all commits reachable from `master`, excluding all commits reachable from the above branch list:

```
git rev-list --before=... -n 1 master --not $(git for-each-ref \
  --format='%(refname:short)' refs/heads | grep -v '^master$')
```

This time, when git hits commit `D`, it's excluded, because it's on branch `develop`.  (It's also on branch `master`: a commit can be on many branches simultaneously.)  Commit `C`, however, is *only* on branch `master`, so when it qualifies for the `--before` restriction, it is listed, and then the `-n 1` makes `git rev-list` stop (so that you don't also get commit `A`).

The flaw with this method occurs if someone deletes branch `develop`.  This leaves the actual revision graph unchanged, but the `develop` label no longer exists to point to commit `D`.  Thus, there is no reason that `git rev-list` can see to exclude commit `D`, so that's the revision you will see.

---

Here's an exercise you should try.  Suppose I give you only this graph of commits (having peeled off some or most of the labels):

```
...--o--o--o---o--o   <-- branch
      \       /
       o--o--o
```

How did I make this graph?  Did I check out a side branch, `feature`, and make some commits there, then check out `branch` and (perhaps under another user name) make some commits there too, and then eventually `git merge feature` into `branch` but then delete `feature`?  Or, were there two different people working on `branch`, and one made some commits and `push`ed first, while the other made some commits but pushed second and got an error from `push`?  If the second person then did a `pull` and thus merged and pushed, would that produce the same graph?

---

<sup>1</sup>Based on the source, it appears to look only at the committer date, not the author date.  I could not find this documented anywhere (I've been wondering about this, off and on, for quite a while).

Comment: Thanks for providing detailed explanation that provides a very good idea about what is possible and what is not. It seems that none of those are perfect, and chances are that, they may not provide "better" snapshots of `master` than the very first command in the answer.