# How to create a workspace in Git based on a specific timestamp data

Tags: git

we currently are using Git for our codebase config mgmt.

i create a workspace with the repository details. when i sync i would like to sync to the codebase ...is there any option i can use to sync to the codebase at a specific timestamp so that i can replicate someone else codebase created at that time.

Reason for asking about timestamp: Only information i have is timestamp.

Could anyone give some inputs.

Thanks a lot for your inputs in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git checkout by date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6990484/git-checkout-by-date)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like i found the answer after asking around

Answer for anyone who might find it useful

git log --until='date'

git checkout

This sets my workspace to a specific head and the code content