# How to make a GIT branch based on a date?

Tags: git

I know that we can do git checkout based on a date  ([git checkout by date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6990484/git-checkout-by-date)).

Example:

```
git checkout `git rev-list -n 1 --before="2009-07-27 13:37" master`
```

However, how can we create a GIT branch based on the date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way you could create a branch would be to just use `git checkout -b` from the commit on which you find yourself after doing the `git checkout` you described in your question.  That is, try the following:

```
git checkout `git rev-list -n 1 --before="2009-07-27 13:37" master`
```

and then

```
git checkout -b some_branch_from_above_date
```