# Checkout most recent commit on any branch

Tags: git, bitbucket

I would like to checkout the latest commit on an active repository of any branch. That's the first commit when you sort your Bitbucket repo in the "Network" section.

My use case is a tool which uses code from latest changes in multiple submodules to analyze if those changes have led to a better evaluation metric. I'm doing it though a Jenkinsfile

I tried:

```
git checkout HEAD
```

but that only checks out the latest commit in the current branch.

Comment: What did you try?  Did something not work for you?

Comment: Check this answer is a good starting point: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6990525/2319299

Comment: @MatteoRagni Looks like `git rev-list` requires that you specify a particular branch. I need any change made to any branch.

Comment: I'm not in condition for testing by myself, but isn't `--branches=*` the option that considers all branches?

Comment: @MatteoRagni You're right, that works!

Comment: cool, glad that it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git rev-list -n1 origin --branches=* | xargs git checkout`

Comment: This is a combination of Matteo's answer and the fact that I wanted to checkout the commit. It works.

Answer (score 0):

```
git checkout :/.
```

The `:/` syntax is "the most recent commit whose message contains a match for the expression", and `.` is "any character".