# Don't know how to checkout the real code from terminal

Tags: git

I'm using Mac terminal for git and I'm trying checkout my other version of log by command `git checkout` but when I'm executing the command it's showing me that head is now at 12344 but I want to see the code at that time, I don't know how to do it. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could [checkout by date](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6990682/6309).
Or even using a relative date

```
git checkout `git rev-list -n 1 --before="3 days ago" master`
```

But be aware your checkout will be in [detached head mode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3965714/6309).