# Checkout via Tortoise GIT and SourceTree with a specific date

Tags: git

We have a project in git..We didn't branched out so far..Several check-ins has been went every day throughout the year..However we want to checkout with specific date now

Is it possible via Tortoise Git and Source Tree?

Please kindly let me know the steps.

Thanks

Comment: You should be able to check out any commit you like, so I don't understand your problem. I typically use the commandline and `gitk` though, so maybe these pieces of software are a lot different. Please also don't ask two questions (Tortoise Git and Source Tree) in one.

Comment: Assume i have committed throughout the year..Now i want to checkout all the files till Sep 17,2019. How to do it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+checkout+date

Comment: I would like to know whether it is possible via client - Tortoise Git or Source Tree

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in "[How to checkout in Git by date?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6990682/6309)"; [`git reflog`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog) is not reliable

[git rev-list](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-list) has access to *all* your history:

```
git checkout $(git rev-list -1 --first-parent --before="2019-09-17 00:00" master)
```

To do so in Source Tree, for instance, you can use a **[custom action](https://confluence.atlassian.com/sourcetreekb/using-git-in-custom-actions-785323500.html)**:

> - For Windows, the Custom Actions configuration is located in `Tools > Options > Custom Actions`;
> - For Mac, the Custom Actions configuration is located in `Preferences > Custom Actions`.
>
> [image: https://confluence.atlassian.com/sourcetreekb/files/785323500/785323477/1/1444967006147/CustomAction1.png]
>
> To run the custom actions, simply open up `Actions > Custom Actions > Select` your custom actions:
>
> [image: https://confluence.atlassian.com/sourcetreekb/files/785323500/785323480/1/1444967006069/CustomAction4.png]