# Reset entire project to specific point in time with Git

Tags: git, git-reset

I basically made a huge mess out of my git history in the last hour or two. How can I, and is it possible, revert the entire project (all the branches) to a state it was few hours ago?

I know there is this `git reset --hard master@{"10 minutes ago"}` but I want to do thi for the entire project and all the branches

Comment: You cannot do that in one sweep. You should do it branch by branch. You don't need to checkout every branch — just run `git branch --force xyzzy xyzzy@{"10 minutes ago"}`. Advice — make a full backup before starting.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to checkout in Git by date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6990484/how-to-checkout-in-git-by-date)

Answer (score 0):

Unless you do what you are about to do, you only ever *add* commits to a repository.  This means it's really easy to recover.  [phd's method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72000807/reset-entire-project-to-specific-point-in-time-with-git#comment127225737_72000807) will work in general *except* for the *current* branch, as `git branch` is not allowed to alter the hash ID stored in the current branch name.  To modify the *current* branch, you must use `git reset`, probably with `--hard`, as you suggested.

#### What to know before you start

Git is not really about *branches*, and definitely not about *files*.  Git is about *commits*.  We (humans) organize our commits *by* branch names, and call them "branches"—which makes a mess of things because we call multiple different things "branches", as if they were all the same—and each commit *stores* files, but the things Git "cares about", as it were, are the commits.  So, to use Git, you need to know, at a sort of instinctive gut level, what a Git commit is and does for you.  If you don't *know* this, you'll find yourself in trouble.

A Git commit:

- Is numbered.  Every commit has a unique number, expressed in [hexadecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal); Git calls this a commit's *hash ID* or, more generally, *object ID*.  These things look random, but are not actually *random;* they are just not *predictable*.

  When I say *unique* I mean **unique**: not "sort of unique", or "unique in isolation", but with the absolute meaning of the word [unique](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/unique), exclusive of meaning numbers 3 and 5.  (Meaning 5 here is the weak version of "unique" that [descriptivists](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/descriptivist) will include.<sup>1</sup>)  When you make a new commit, it gets a *new* number that has never been used before, and after that, it can never be used again.

  (The numbering scheme Git uses internally is doomed to fail someday.  The size of the hash IDs puts this off—we hope for long enough after we're dead and nobody cares, e.g., billions of years—but Git is slowly moving from SHA-1 to SHA-256, because SHA-1 turned out to be insufficient, at least in the case of active sabotage.)
- Is read-only.  The numbering scheme requires this: the hash ID is actually a cryptographic checksum of the contents.  If the contents are to be changed, the result is a new object with a *different hash ID*, and the original object remains.  So we can't—quite—*remove* anything from a repository.  We can only *add to it*.  (We can *fake* removing something by just no longer using it, which is what we're going to do.)
- Holds two things: a full snapshot of every file, and some metadata.  I won't go into a lot of detail here but some of this is pretty important, so I'll cover something about the metadata now.

The metadata *in* each commit is called "metadata" because it is information *about* that commit.  This includes your name and email address (copied from your `user.name` and `user.email` setting and, once stored in a commit, completely unchangeable like everything about every commit).  It includes any log message you'd like to include, to tell yourself and/or others *why* you made this particular commit.  **And, for Git's own purposes, every commit holds a list of *previous commit* hash IDs.**  This list is usually exactly one element long, and we call that one hash ID the *parent* of this commit.

It's this parentage information, as stored inside each commit, that forms the history.  The result is that the commits *are* the history: history, in a Git repository, is no more or less than the *commits* in the repository.  But what's crucial at this point is *how we find this history*.  If a commit number looks random—and it does—how will we find the *latest* commit?

---

<sup>1</sup>I myself am both descriptivist and prescriptivist.  As in the Alan Parsons song *Turn it Up*, sitting on fences [makes me] a pain in the ...

---

#### Finding the latest commit

Let's draw a simple chain of ordinary (single-parent<sup>2</sup>) commits, as found in a typical small repository:

```
... <-F <-G <-H
```

Here `H` stands in for the hash ID of the *latest* commit.  Whatever that actual hash ID is, Git can use it to retrieve the commit, which gets Git both the metadata and the snapshot.  Using the metadata, Git can tell you who made the commit and what their log message was.  But Git can also use the metadata in `H` to find the raw hash ID of `H`'s *parent* commit `G`.

Using the hash ID for `G`, Git can retrieve commit `G`.  That gets it a snapshot and log message and so on.  But that also gets Git the raw hash ID of earlier commit `F`.  Since `F` *is* a commit, Git can now get it too, and that has a snapshot and log message and a parent, and Git can work backwards from `F`, and so on.  Repeat this long enough and Git will eventually come back to the very first commit (which, as in footnote 2, won't have any parents, so that `git log` can finally stop).

So Git can tell us the entire history of this one-branch repository *provided* Git can find hash ID `H`.  Where will it get this hash ID?  Are we going to be forced to memorize it ourselves?  Can we type it in correctly even if we *can* remember it?

To save our poor human brains from this task, Git will store the *latest* hash ID for our one branch in a *branch name*.  We'll pick some name, `main` or `master` or `trunk` or whatever, and have Git store the hash ID of the *last* commit—the "tip of the branch"—in that name:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master
```

If we want to make a new *branch*, we just have Git create a new name, also pointing to commit `H`, like this:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- br1, master
```

Creating a second `br2` branch gives:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- br1, br2, master
```

Of course, now we need a way to know which *name* we're using to find commit `H`, so we'll have Git attach a very special name, `HEAD`, to just one of these three *branch* names:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- br1, br2, master (HEAD)
```

This means we're "on" branch `master`: `git status` will say `on branch master`.  We're *using* commit `H` to get files, but we're *finding* commit `H` through the *name* `master`.

---

<sup>2</sup>A commit with *two or more* parents, in Git, is a *merge commit*.  At least one commit in any non-empty repository has *no* parent: that's the first commit anyone ever made.  This kind of commits is a *root commit*.  Most commits in most repositories, though, have one parent, and are therefore "ordinary" commits.

Note that a zero-parent root commit, or a two-parent merge commit, still has just a single snapshot of all files.  In the case of an ordinary commit, the difference between the *parent's* snapshot and *this commit's* snapshot will show what you—or the author of this commit—*changed*.  In the case of a *merge* commit, there is one difference from one parent, and a *different* difference from the *other* parent, so there's no longer a single obvious way to describe what *changed*.  That's what makes merge commits tricky.

Note that the `git log -p` command simply *does not bother to show* a merge commit as "changes", skipping right over the hard part.  This is deceptive; watch out for it.

---

#### Growing a branch

Let's now switch to branch `br1`, with `git switch br1` or the old `git checkout br1` (both do the same thing).  The result is:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- br1 (HEAD), br2, master
```

We're *still using commit `H`* but now we're doing so through the *name* `br1`.

We now make a new commit in the usual way (edit files, run `git add`, run `git commit`, enter a log message).  I'm going to skip over a huge number of important details about this, specifically, about where all the files are: remember that the files *stored in* commit `H` are literally read-only and therefore cannot be changed, so the files we're editing must not be *in* commit `H`, and in fact they're not *in* Git at all.  But to keep this answer short, we won't go into those details.  Instead, we'll just assume that you know all of this, and that when you run `git commit`, you know where Git gets the new snapshot.  (It's not your working tree.)

In any case, when you *do* run `git commit` and have provided all the details, Git makes the new commit: a new snapshot and metadata.  This new commit gets a new, unique hash ID, never to be used again in any Git repository anywhere.  It looks random, and is big and ugly and is too difficult for humans, so we'll call this new commit `I`, and draw it in:

```
             I   <-- ...
            /
...--F--G--H   <-- ...
```

Here's the sneaky part: since we are *on* `br1`, Git now *updates the name* `br1` to point to `I`.  So we can fill in the three dots that appear twice above like so:

```
             I   <-- br1 (HEAD)
            /
...--F--G--H   <-- br2, master
```

The special name `HEAD` remains attached to the name `br1`, but the name `br1` itself no longer points to `H`.  Now it points to `I`.  Commits up through `H` are on *all three* branches, and commit `I` is *only* on `br1`.

If we make a second commit on `br1`, we get:

```
             I--J   <-- br1 (HEAD)
            /
...--F--G--H   <-- br2, master
```

We can now `git switch br2` (or the same with `checkout` as usual) and make new commits that are only on `br2`, and they will extend `br2` the way our new commits above extended `br1`:

```
             I--J   <-- br1
            /
...--F--G--H   <-- master
            \
             K--L   <-- br2 (HEAD)
```

Now all three *names* select three different commits: `master` continues to select `H` as before, but `br1` selects commit `J`, and `br2` selects commit `L`.

Here's a capsule review; make sure you understand each of these points:

- `HEAD` controls which branch name is the *current name*.
- The current name points to the current commit.
- Switching from one name to another changes which *files* are *checked out* of that commit, into the area where we get to work on / with files.
- The files we work on / with, in our work area, are not actually *in Git*.  The snapshots *are* in Git, and are extracted by `git switch` or `git checkout`, which attaches `HEAD` to the desired branch name.
- Making a new commit makes a new snapshot-and-metadata, which gets a new, unique hash ID.  This new commit points backwards to whichever commit we *were* using to *make* the new commit; and as soon as Git has made the new commit, it writes the new hash ID into the current *branch name*.  So the act of making a commit is what grows the branch.  The branch that grows is the one we selected earlier, with `git switch` or `git checkout`.  The parent of the *new* commit is the commit we selected at that time.

#### "Removing" a commit

Because of the peculiar way that commits *are* the history and are read-only, we can't actually *remove* a commit.  But because we *find* commits by using a *branch name* to select the *latest* commit ... well, suppose that instead of having the name "move forward", we force the name itself to "move backward"?  That is, suppose we have:

```
          I   <-- br1 (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H   <-- master
```

and we force Git to move `br1` *back* one commit, to where it was just before we made new commit `I`?  We'll get:

```
          I   ???
         /
...--G--H   <-- br1 (HEAD), master
```

**Commit `I` still exists, but if we go look at history, we won't see it.**  Whether we ask Git to start from name `br1` or from name `master`, we'll see commit `H`, then commit `G`, and so on.  We'll never move *forward* to see commit `I`.  It's *as if* it is gone!

Since commits are guaranteed never to change, it's as though commit `I` had never occurred.

If we have this:

```
             I--J   <-- br1
            /
...--F--G--H   <-- master (HEAD)
            \
             K--L   <-- br2
```

and we force `br1` and `br2` both to go back one step, we'll get this:

```
             I   <-- br1
            /
...--F--G--H   <-- master (HEAD)
            \
             K   <-- br2
```

(where I simply have not bothered to draw in the commits we can't find any more).  The two commits we just "removed" aren't really *gone*, but they might as well be: we won't see them.

#### Shrinking is not quite the opposite of growing

When we *grow* a branch, we do that by:

- checking out the branch by name, which selects the latest commit;
- working on the editable not-in-Git files;
- adding the updated files and committing

and it's the `git commit` step that grows the branch.  It only grows the *current* branch.

When we go to *shrink* a branch, we're allowed to forcibly change any *non-current* branch name, to make that name select *any commit we like* (including the current commit).  We just run:

```
git branch -f <name> <new-hash-ID>
```

For the new hash ID, we can substitute in any expression that is described in [the gitrevisions documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions).  This includes the `name@{time}` formulation, such as `master@{"10 minutes ago"}`.  If you want to see what commit that *would* select, use:

```
git show master@{10.minutes.ago}
```

or:

```
git log master@{10.minutes.ago}
```

(I've used the dot `.` instead of a space here to avoid needing quotes, although in some command-line interpreters you might still need quotes anyway; the space-vs-dot trick might not help *you* the way it helps *me*.)

But this won't work for any branch we have actively checked out.  In a standard Git repository, with only one working tree, that's the one particular branch we're "on"; if you use `git worktree add`, there may be additional branch names that are "locked up" like this.  To change the branch we're *on*, we have to use `git reset`, and pick one of `--soft`, `--mixed`, or `--hard`.  That's because of some of the stuff I skipped over above: we need to tell Git what to do with the *usable copies* of the files that came out of the commit.  Using `--hard` tell Git *throw out the old usable copies and put in new ones from the new commit I selected*, so that's what we'd normally like for this case.

Since the files `git reset` will throw out here are *not in Git* in the first place, Git won't be able to help you get them back after you throw them out.  So be very careful with `git reset --hard`!