# Is there any difference between $() and `` in Bash?

Tags: bash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Shell Programming: What's the difference between $(command) and `command`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4708549/shell-programming-whats-the-difference-between-command-and-command)

It seems there is no difference between

```
$()
```

and

```
``
```

For example,

```
$(date)
```

is the same as

```
`date`
```

Any suggestion ?

Comment: exact duplicate of http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/5778/1383

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's the difference between `man` command and `stackoverflow.com`? :)

> When the old-style backquote form of substitution is used, backslash
>   retains its literal meaning except when followed  by  $,  `, or \. 
>   The first backquote not preceded by a backslash terminates the command
>   substitution.  When using the $(command) form, all characters between
>   the parentheses make up the command; none  are treated specially.

so, if you put `date` inside, it's more or less the same.