# What is the difference between backticks and $() in a Bash script?

Tags: bash, backticks

I see two different forms in Bash scripts which seem to do the same:

```
`some command`
```

and

```
$(some command)
```

What is the difference between the two, and when should I use each one of them?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

There isn't any semantic difference. The backtick syntax is the older and less powerful version. See [man bash](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash), section "Command Substitution".

If your shell supports the `$()` syntax, prefer it because it can be nested.

Comment: I see that backticks can also be nested. For example: `\`echo \\`foo\\`\``

Comment: @MishaMoroshko: Expressions like `\`echo \`foo\`\` (as opposed to `$(echo $(foo))`) won't work in general because of the inherent ambiguity because each `\`` can be opening or closing. It might work for special cases due to luck or special features.

Comment: There _is_ a semantic difference: backtick syntax handles backslashes in a different and non-obvious manner.  See: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082

Comment: I am using a makefile.  In that makefile I have the following command

gcc  `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0` -o $@  $< `pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0`

If I replace the backticks to the bash function call:
gcc $(pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0)  -o $@  $<  $(pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0)

the makefile fails    So, via the make utility, there is a difference.
The command line execution does not fail.

Comment: Another difference is: `echo foo \`#comment\`` vs `echo foo $(#comment)`. The second one doesn't work. (Used for commenting in a multi-line command.)