# Need to assign the contents of a text file to a variable in a bash script

Tags: bash

I am very new to making bash scripts, but my goal here is to take a .txt file I have and assign the string of words in the txt file to a variable. I have tried this (no clue if I am on the right track or not).

```
#!/bin/bash
FILE="answer.txt"
file1="cat answer.txt"
print $file1
```

When I run this, I get

```
Warning: unknown mime-type for "cat" -- using "application/octet-stream"
Error: no such file "cat"
Error: no "print" mailcap rules found for type "text/plain"
```

What can I do to make this work?

Edit**
When I change it to:

```
#!/bin/bash
    FILE="answer.txt"
    file1=$(cat answer.txt)
    print $file1
```

I get this instead:

```
Warning: unknown mime-type for "This" -- using "application/octet-stream"
Warning: unknown mime-type for "text" -- using "application/octet-stream"
Warning: unknown mime-type for "string" -- using "application/octet-stream"
Warning: unknown mime-type for "should" -- using "application/octet-stream"
Warning: unknown mime-type for "be" -- using "application/octet-stream"
Warning: unknown mime-type for "a" -- using "application/octet-stream"
Warning: unknown mime-type for "varible." -- using "application/octet-stream"
Error: no such file "This"
Error: no such file "text"
Error: no such file "string"
Error: no such file "should"
Error: no such file "be"
Error: no such file "a"
Error: no such file "varible."
```

When I enter cat answer.txt it prints out this text string should be a varible like it should but, I still can't get the bash to do that with the varible.

Comment: As I said in my answer you're using print instead of echo. Also, you probably don't need the `FILE="answer.txt"` you're not using it anywhere.

Comment: `print` is Korn shell, if using Bash you can only use `echo` (which is also supported by Korn shell).

Comment: `Warning: unknown mime-type for "cat" -- using "application/octet-stream"` is an error message from `print` belonging to the `mailcap` package. Completely unrelated to bash/ksh/any shell.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

In bash, `$ (< answer.txt)` is equivalent to `$ (cat answer.txt)`, but built in and thus faster and safer. See [the bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html).

I suspect you're running this [`print`](http://man.cx/print):

```
NAME  
    run-mailcap, see, edit, compose, print − execute programs via entries in the mailcap file
```

Comment: It's not really a shorthand. It's, according to the bash reference manual _equivalent by faster_. This is definitely _the_ answer to the OP. (It should be the accepted one). You should also mention how to print the expansion of `$file1`: `echo "$file1"`.

Comment: Nice catch that the error message really meant he typed "print" instead of "printf", which is what brought me here.

Comment: That's not a shorthand but a builtin, therefore, it avoids shelling out to cat, and is thus much much faster. This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: The full example is `file1="$(< answer.txt)"`

Answer (score 94):

You need the backticks to capture output from a command (and you probably want `echo` instead of `print`):

```
file1=`cat answer.txt`
echo $file1
```

Comment: since this is marked as solution, please note that the use of `$(cat answer.txt)` is 
encouraged over the proposed solution since it works without special characters, is more readable and robust (e.g. supports more shells).
cf: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4708569/160799

Comment: This will line breaks with a space and you end up with a single long line in the bash variable.

Answer (score 44):

The `$()` construction returns the `stdout` from a command.

```
file_contents=$(cat answer.txt)
```

Comment: +1; more specifically, it is called command substitution: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html

Comment: That's not strictly speaking true.  The result of this command is 0 (which is stored in $?), the **output** of this command is the contents of the file.

Answer (score 1):

Use command substitution with caution because it removes trailing new lines that makes the variable and the input file not identical, for example:

```
$ printf 'a\n\n' > input.txt
$ md5 < input.txt
94364860a0452ac23f3dac45f0091d81
$ x=$(cat input.txt)
$ printf %s "$x" | md5
0cc175b9c0f1b6a831c399e269772661
$ printf %s "$x" | od -ta
0000000    a                                                            
0000001
```

To make the file and the variable identical, add an extra byte and then remove it later:

```
$ x=$(cat input.txt && echo .)
$ x=${x%.}
$ printf %s "$x" | md5
94364860a0452ac23f3dac45f0091d81
$ printf %s "$x" | od -ta
0000000    a  nl  nl                                                    
0000003
```