# Date format with cat command

Tags: linux

I like to get todays entries from log file so that I can send that to my email every day.
This is my command, its not working please help.

```
cat /var/log/fail2ban.log | grep "date +%Y\-%m\-%d"
```

Comment: You probably want backtick "`" rather than quotes.

Comment: Welcome to SO, if that solved, you should [accept an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/141005), so that others browsing this thread can be benefitted.

Answer (score 1):

I will put my comment as an answer.

You want this:

```
cat /var/log/fail2ban.log | grep `date +%Y-%m-%d`
```

The text between the two backticks `  is executed by your shell, and is replaced by the output of the command.

Comment: backtics are [deprecated](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4708569/297323) perhaps update your answer with `$(...)`

Comment: I like to get yesterday entries from log file so that I can send that to my email every day.
This command will provide today’s from log file 

cat /var/log/fail2ban.log | grep `date +%Y\-%m\-%d`

how do i rewrite this command for yesterday entries?