# Using $# in bash loops

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I am trying to understand why this loop does not print a number for each arguments supplied to the script.

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in {1..$#}; do
  echo $i
done
```

Instead, when supplied e.g. 3 arguments, it outputs

```
{1..3}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression `{}` does not accept variables.

To do so, you need to work with for example `seq`. The following will make it::

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in $(seq 1 $#); do
  echo $i
done
```

Note that `$()` is equivalent to ``` `` ```. That is, it performs a command substitution. For example:

```
$ d=$(echo "hello")
$ echo $d
hello
```

You can see more information in [Shell Programming: What's the difference between $(command) and `command`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4708549/shell-programming-whats-the-difference-between-command-and-command).

#### Tests

```
$ ./a
$

$ ./a a b c
1
2
3
```

Comment: Thank you. Can you explain what the dollarsign does in this context? I understand the dollarsign as a prefix to refer to variables, but I don't see any assignment in the parentheses.

Comment: Thank you. So seq is actually an executable and not a language construct. It makes good sense.

Comment: Exactly! You explained it better than me :) See for example `$ which seq` that returns something like `/usr/bin/seq`.

Answer (score 1):

Brace expansion occurs *before* variable expansion

http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Expansions