# how to transfer files of different extensions from one server to another on linux?

Tags: shell, unix, ssh, sftp, scp

Below are the files in my local server

```
-rw-r----- 1 root root 0 Sep 25 15:03 one.xml
-rw-r----- 1 root root 0 Sep 25 15:03 two.xml
-rw-r----- 1 root root 0 Sep 25 15:03 data.csv
-rw-r----- 1 root root 0 Sep 25 15:03 free.png
-rw-r----- 1 root root 0 Sep 25 15:04 loaded.jpeg
```

I know transfering files of same extension as below

```
    /usr/bin/sftp ${user}@${HostName} <<EOF
    cd $InputPath
    lcd $OutputPath
    put *.csv
    exit
EOF

scp ${InputPath}/*.csv ${user}@${HostName}:$OutputPath
```

But every time when i run the script i need to transfer only files with xml and jpeg extensions. ssh,scp,SFTP can be used. Any hep please??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with something like this:

```
*.{jpeg,xml}
```

All together:

```
scp ${InputPath}/*.{jpeg,xml} ${user}@${HostName}:$OutputPath
```

#### Test

```
$ ls
a.jpeg  a.png  a.xml 
$ ls *{jpeg,xml}
a.jpeg  a.xml
```

Comment: Thanks.Above cmd is working.Now i am trying to take fileExtns into a variable as Extns=jpeg,xml
scp ${InputPath}/*.{$Extns} ${user}@${HostName}:$OutputPath  But this is throwing some error. Any way to handle this?

Comment: As you can read in http://stackoverflow.com/a/18981544/1983854 , `Brace expansion occurs before variable expansion`, so I guess there is no way to do so.