# Fish equivalent of bash $(command) notation

Tags: shell, fish, command-substitution

I am currently trying out the fish shell instead of using bash. One type of notation I'm having trouble learning the fish-equivalent notation for is `$(command)`, similar to how it is described in [this SOF post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4708549/shell-programming-whats-the-difference-between-command-and-command). How do I write this using fish? Keep in mind that I could use backslash characters around the command I want to evaluate, but the linked post and other posts discourage this because it is an old style of evaluating commands.

Specifically, this is the bash command I want to convert to fish syntax (for initializing *rbenv* during startup of the shell):

```
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```

Comment: Per [this](http://fishshell.com/docs/2.0/faq.html#faq-subcommand) entry in the fish FAQ, sub-commands are denoted by surrounding them with parenthesis. e.g., `set foo (echo bar); echo $foo` outputs `bar`.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

In fish, `$` is used only for variables. Correct notation equivalent to bash `$(command)` is just `(command)` in fish.

Comment: `eval (docker-machine env default --no-proxy --shell=fish)` :D thanks for the help too

Answer (score 17):

FYI: If you additionally need to use this inside a string:

```
echo "Found "(count $PATH)" paths in PATH env var"
```

Comment: So there is no way around temporarily closing the quote and reopening right after. https://fishshell.com/docs/current/tutorial.html#command-substitutions

Answer (score 9):

Since fish 3.4 ([released](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/relnotes.html#fish-3-4-0-released-march-12-2022) March 2022), `$()`-substitution is supported. It works the same as `()`-substitution, but can be used inside double-quoted strings.

Comment: I want to use ``` alias math=math ()" ``` so that I can use brackets in the calculation by default. Is this doable?

Comment: @Pranav please [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) for the best chance of someone writing an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Watch out that `()` and `$()` in fish are not totally equivalent to `$()` in bash.

**Fish only splits command substitutions on newlines.**

- In fish `cmd $(echo "A B C")` is equivalent to `cmd 'A B C'`, but
- in bash `cmd $(echo "A B C")` is equivalent to `cmd A B C`.

But `cmd $(echo -e "A\nB\nC")` is indeed equivalent in fish and bash.