# bash syntax error in sed command inside function, works fine on command line

Tags: bash, sed

I've got a a bash script with two functions, one is the main function which includes a case command, that case command will then call a second function and pass a specific argument.

In the second function I have a command that works on the command line, but when run as part of the bash script I get the following error:

```
: line 57: syntax error near unexpected token `('
: line 57: `           local DATE=`echo $URL|sed -r 's/.*____([0-9]{1,2})_([0-9]{1,2})_([0-9]{1,2}).*/20\3-\1-\2/;s/-([0-9]{1})-/-0\1-/;s/-([0-9]{1})$/-0\1/'`'
```

the function is,

```
dlshow ()
{
    local URL=$1
    echo "URL: "$URL
    local DATE=`echo $URL|sed -r 's/.*____([0-9]{1,2})_([0-9]{1,2})_([0-9]{1,2}).*/20\3-\1-\2/;s/-([0-9]{1})-/-0\1-/;s/-([0-9]{1})$/-0\1/'`
```

I can't figure out why as a bash command I get the error.

Comment: I can't see an error there. I suspect you have an extra/missing single quote elsewhere in the script

Comment: Its better you post what you like to do, input/output.  This way, we may help you out.

Comment: better to add some sample of value. I suspect that $URL have special char interpreted. Try with echo "${URL}"

Comment: glenn: you got it! I added a part to the case command with an errant ' and that messed up the script.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
echo $URL | sed -e '...' |  { read DATE ; ... ; }
```

Comment: I don't see why the evaluation of the sed script should fail, and your statement regarding the quotes and backticks is false.

Comment: @user2719058 I have removed the statement. But avoiding backticks is always a good idea: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4708549/shell-programming-whats-the-difference-between-command-and-command

Comment: Unfortunately, doing so will assign `DATE` inside the subshell defined by the pipe, and not globally. Fix this with a command substitution as so: `{ read DATE ; ... ; } < <(echo $URL | sed -e '...')`.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf: that's just tossing around the command list inbetween the curlies, isn't it?

Comment: @user2719058 it is, but it will make `DATE` available in subsequent commands.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Ah sorry, I got confused by the curlies; of course you're right. Although I would then simply drop the curlies and attach the redirection to the `read` builtin alone.

Comment: @user2719058 I have no ideas what your final goal is.. so I just took the command (with grouping) given here and adapted it. I'm not even sure the `read` is mandatory: `DATE=$(echo $URL | sed -e '...')` might be enough.

Comment: @user2719058 Btw you can remove the pipe and the `echo`: `sed -e '...' <<<$URL`

Comment: I'll have to look at how  { read DATE ; ... ; } works, that's a new method to me.

user2719058: googled that, did not know about here strings, good to know! thanks!

problem answered in the above response, thanks for all the info!

Comment: Please explain why the backticks cause the problem.