# Feed line number to sed

Tags: shell, sed, xargs

I  have a piped unix script which finally yields a line number to me in the subject file.
Now,I need to print out the file contents from this particular line to the end.
Is it possible to feed the line number to sed via xargs,for sed to print out the desired.

```
.....|tail -1 | cut -f 1 | xargs sed ...?
```

Is this possible?

Comment: There's probably a way to do this, but are you sure it wouldn't be easier to enclose the whole thing in backticks? sed -n "`.....|tail -1 | cut -f 1`p" filename

Comment: @Beta Backtics should not be use, use parentheses `$(code)` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4708549/shell-programming-whats-the-difference-between-command-and-command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
..... | tail -1 | cut -f 1 | xargs -i sed -n '{},$p' your_file
```

Comment: Doesnt work - just prints the line itself - rather than to the end of the file

Comment: Sorry, I missed that in the OP.  Edited to add this.