# Shellscript: meaning of $()

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I see in a shell script code like:

```
for i in $(seq 1 5); do
  # do something
done
```

I am used to writing same logic as:

```
for i in `seq 1 5 | xargs`; do
  # do something
done
```

Is there a difference between both the approaches?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4708549/shell-programming-whats-the-difference-between-command-and-command

Comment: Using `xargs` is pointless; just ``for i in `seq 1 5`; do`` would do.

Answer (score 0):

This $() approach seems to be the modern approach as it supports nesting. More details here: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082