# searching for a certain timeframe using awk does not work

Tags: unix, awk

I need to extract log messages for a certain timeframe from a log file. following does not work.
Please help

```
hour=`date +%H`
hour=`expr $hour - 1`
echo $hour
start1=$hour":00:00"
start="$start1"
end1=$hour":59:59"
end="$end1"

awk '$0 >= $start && $0 <= $end' server.log
```

But the following command works from the command line
    awk '$0 >= "11:00:00" && $0 <= "11:59:59"' server.log

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are reading the variable wrong with `awk`.  Here is one way to read them

```
awk '$0 >= s && $0 <= e' s="$start" e="$end" file
```

You should also not use old and out dated backtics, but use parentheses like this:

```
hour=$(date +%H)
```

To remove one hour, do

```
hour=$(date +%H -d 1h)
```

To get minutes:

```
date +%H":00:00" -d 1h
11:00:00
date +%H":59:59" -d 1h
11:59:59
```

And all in one go:

```
awk '$0>=s && $0<=e' s='$(date +%H":00:00" -d 1h)' e='$(date +%H":59:59" -d 1h)' file
```

Ref EDs comment:

```
awk -v s='$(date +%H":00:00" -d 1h)' -v e='$(date +%H":59:59" -d 1h)' '$0>=s && $0<=e' file
```

Comment: Is there some programming language out there where initializing variables at the end of the program is the natural way of doing things? I've been seeing a few people do this in awk lately and I'm just trying to figure out where the idea is coming from that it's better to init variables AFTER the text of the program than before it. In awk the 2 approaches are not even equivalent since variables init-ed after the script will be uninitialized in the BEGIN so it's not just hard to read, it introduces non-obvious complexity and potential bugs.

Comment: Why should people not use backticks, is there any actual disadvantage, other than it looking ambiguous maybe.

Comment: @Jidder Do a search for it, or read post like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4708549/shell-programming-whats-the-difference-between-command-and-command  But in general its more easy to read and better with nesting.