# how to store the awk command output value into some variable in ksh

Tags: shell, ksh

```
foundflag =  awk -F" " 'FNR==NR{A[$arg1 OFS $PREVFILE];next}
!($arg1 OFS $PREVFILE in A){X++} END{if(!X){print "No diff."} 
else {print "Diff found."}} $arg1 ${PREVFILE}
echo $foundflag
```

here am comparing two files and want to store awk command result into some variable please help in Ksh script.

Comment: How are `$arg1` and  `$PREVFILE` working inside single quote.

Comment: hi there is single quote in editing it has got inserted.

Comment: if i assigned something like this its not working  if(!X){foundflag=2;print "0"}

Answer (score 1):

I think what You need is:

```
foundflag=`awk ....`
```

- remove spaces arounf `=`
- put the command into reverse quotes (``)

Comment: you right sir, i have used ' instead of `.. now its working thank u

Comment: foundflag=`awk -F" " 'FNR==NR{A[$arg1 OFS $PREVFILE];next} !($arg1 OFS $PREVFILE in A){X++} END{if(!X){print "0"} else {print "1"}}' $arg1 ${PREVFILE}` whats wrong here, why the comparison not working

Comment: @jcrshankar I don't catch the idea of the algorithm. As it was already mentoned in question's comments - $arg1 and $PREVFILE are inside of single quotes (probably not working as You expect). I would sugest dumping/inspecting the contents of A at the END.

Comment: Use the $(..) for the same result. Helpful for more complex situations.

Answer (score 1):

Or use [command substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html). [The backticks/gravemarks have been deprecated in favor of $()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4708549/shell-programming-whats-the-difference-between-command-and-command)

```
foundflag=$(awk....)
```

Also note where cannot be any space around  **[the assignment operator (no space before and after)](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/varassignment.html)**