# Put result of command in a environment variable

Tags: bash, shell, centos, environment-variables

I would like to put the result of the command `date +"%Y.%m.%d" -d "yesterday"` in an environment variable.

I tried `export YESTERDAY_DATE=date +"%Y.%m.%d" -d "yesterday"` but got an error stating the identifier is not correst.

How could I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
export YESTERDAY_DATE=`date +"%Y.%m.%d" -d "yesterday"`
```

Comment: I was using ' instead of `. Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, you can use this syntax:

```
YESTERDAY_DATE=$(date +"%Y.%m.%d" -d "yesterday")
```

See also here:

[What's the difference between $(command) and `command` in shell programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4708549/shell-programming-whats-the-difference-between-command-and-command)

Edit: Missing the capability of commenting the above solution: That's exactly why I prefer $() over ` - it's copy/pasteable (some systems have problems with backticks ...)