# Bash : expression recursion level exceeded (error token is ...)

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I'm writing a program that prints the username and the number of times that the user has logged in, or prints "Unknown user" otherwise.

My code is the following:

```
iden=$1
c='last | grep -w -c $iden'
if (( $c > 1 ))
then
    echo "$iden $c"
else
    echo "Unknown user"
fi
```

And I keep getting this error:

> -bash: ((: last | grep -w -c 123: expression recursion level exceeded (error token is "c 123")

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To store the output of a command in a variable you need to say `var=$(command)`. Hence, use:

```
c=$(last | grep -w -c "$iden")  # always good to quote the variables
```

instead of

```
c='last | grep -w -c $iden'
```

If you are learning Bash scripting, it is always handy to paste your code in [ShellCheck](http://www.shellcheck.net/) to see the problems you may have.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this too:

```
c=`last | grep -w -c "$iden"`
```

Comment: Backticks and `$()` are equivalent and in, in fact, `$()` is prefered since you can nest them. See [Shell Programming: What's the difference between $(command) and `command`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4708549/1983854).