# Use of .* in printf

Tags: bash, unix, printf

I am trying to change the code of someone else. Can anyone explain this line of code to me?

```
xs=`printf "%.*d" 3 $x`
```

The `$x` is the loop variable, I do understand that.

Comment: Aside: If this is modern bash, `printf -v xs '%.*d' 3 "$x"` would be the more efficient way to write this, avoiding the performance overhead of a subshell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `.*` is a way to pad the format. From [Bash-hackers #The printf command](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/printf):

> The precision for a floating- or double-number can be specified by
>   using ., where  is the number of digits for precision.
>   If  is an asterisk (*), the precision is read from the
>   argument that precedes the number to print, like (prints
>   4,3000000000):
>
> printf "%.*f\n" 10 4,3

So by saying

```
xs=`printf "%.*d" 3 $x`
```

`$xs` is getting the number stored in `$x` with three digits of precision. Note also that [it is best to use `$()`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4708549/1983854) and also to quote the parameter:

```
xs=$(printf "%.*d" 3 "$x")
```

See some examples:

```
$ printf "%.*d\n" 3 1
001
$ printf "%.*d\n" 3 1234
1234
```

---

There is a better reference of [`man printf`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf), thanks to Aaron Digulla for pointing it in the comments:

> **The precision**
>
> An optional precision, in the form of a period ('.') followed by an
>   optional decimal digit string. Instead of a decimal digit string one
>   may write "*" or "*m$" (for some decimal integer m) to specify that
>   the precision is given in the next argument, or in the m-th argument,
>   respectively, which must be of type int. (...)

Comment: In this case, it's not precision (which would be after the comma) but padding.

Comment: @AaronDigulla you are right. However, I cannot find the proper documentation reference ([and it seems to be a common problem!](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/84148/40596))

Comment: Actually, you're right. http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf explains it. `*` would be  "width" but `.*` is called "precision". It's usually used for floating point numbers but it also works for integers: "This gives the minimum number of digits to appear for d, i, o, u, x, and X conversions[...]"

Comment: `man printf` isn't necessarily the best resource to use here, since one's shell may provide a version of printf with more/better facilities than the built-in one. Thus, `help printf` is arguably the better resource; the bash-hackers page is also great.

Answer (score 2):

It's displaying an integer with a 0 padding for a size of 3 characters.

```
$ x=4
$ printf "%.*d" 3 $x
004

$ x=12
$ printf "%.*d" 3 $x
012

$ x=9999
$ printf "%.*d" 3 $x
9999
```