# How to call i in a for loop?

Tags: bash

So, this question seems a-specific. It is, because I'm not a BASH-programmer, rather a Biologist-turned-writing-some-useful-scripts-for-my-daily-work-scripter. Anyway. Say, I have a for loop, like so:

```
for CHR $(seq 1 22); do
    echo "Processing chromosome ${CHR}";
done
```

I used to write `seq 1 22` but now I've learned to write $(seq 1 22). Clearly there is a difference in terms of the way you write it. But what is the difference in terms in computer language and interpretation? Can someone explain that to me?

The other thing I learned by simply doing on the command line on our computer cluster, was to call "i" differently. I used to do: `$CHR`. But when I'd have a file name `sometext_chr` to which I'd like to add the number (`sometext_chr$CHR`) that wouldn't work. What does work is `sometext_chr${CHR}`. Why is that? Can someone help me explain the difference?

Again, I know the question is a bit a-specific - I simply didn't know how to otherwise frame it - but I hope someone can teach me the differences.

Thanks and best!

Sander

Comment: Your loop is missing the keyword `in`.

Comment: Also, please try to limit yourself to one question per post. I'm pretty sure that all of these have already been asked and answered before, although maybe not in this combination.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4708549/2088135 is one possible duplicate

Comment: ...otherwise maybe we're just dealing with a syntax error

Comment: ...otherwise maybe it's too broad! :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as a duplicate of the question found by @TomFenech because that particular sub-question is the only one that is focused enough to be acceptable as a good question.

Comment: If you have more questions, ask several questions, not one.

Comment: @TomFenech Thanks for the answer. Very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$(...)` can be nested easily, as the parentheses clearly indicate where an expression starts and ends. Using `, nesting is not so simple, as the start and end symbols are the same.

Your second example is probably from memory, because it's incorrect. `sometext$chr` and `sometext${chr}` would both work the same way. Perhaps what you really meant was a situation like this:

```
$chr_sometext
${chr}_sometext
```

The key point here is that `_` is a valid character in a variable name. As a result, `$chr_sometext` is interpreter as the value of the variable `chr_sometext`. In `${chr}_sometext` the variable is clearly `chr`, and the `_sometext` that follows it is a literal string value. Just like if you wrote `$chrsometext` you wouldn't assume that the `chr` is somehow special. This is the reason you have to add the clarifying braces.

Comment: Thanks for clear answer. Makes sense. This _ is exactly the problem. I'm now changing the scripts I'm using to the curly-brackets method. Thanks again.

Comment: I don't have enough credits to up vote your answer...newbie that I am... :-(

Comment: I know, no worries. Thanks for accepting!