# multiple commands in git alias is not working

Tags: git, terminal

I have the following code in my `.gitconfig` file:

```
[alias]
  john = "!f(){ git branch -r | grep -v '\->' | while read remote; do git branch --track "${remote#origin/}" "$remote"; done; git fetch --all; git pull --all; };f"
```

Which is basically creating an `alias` for pulling every branch on the remote server. But is constantly trowing an error. Can someone help me understand what is going wrong, I've tried dissecting the command, but I can't find what is going wrong.

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: have you tried using single quotes ( `'` instead of `"` ) characters as outer delimiters for your command ? that or escaping your double quotes ( `\"` instead of `"`) *inside* the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape embedded double quotes with backslashes.  For instance:

```
[alias]
    next = "!f() { id=$(git rev-list --reverse --ancestry-path ..master | head -1); test -n \"$id\" && git checkout $id || echo 'no more commits'; }; f"
```

(which I actually have commented out since hardcoding `master` is bogus: this is a leftover from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38541028/1256452)).

You can also wrap long lines with backslash-newline:

```
    next = "!f() { \
        id=$(git rev-list --reverse --ancestry-path ..master | head -1); \
        test -n \"$id\" && git checkout $id || echo 'no more commits'; }; f"
```

(untested, but should work).

All that said, this is wrong:

> Which is basically creating an alias for pulling every branch on the remote server.

Your sample alias attempts to create a new local branch for each remote-tracking branch (which is fine as far as it goes, but not possible in full generality, e.g., if you have both `refs/remotes/origin/zorg` and `refs/remotes/evil/zorg`, you cannot have local branch `zorg` track both remote-tracking branches).  (For scripting purposes, it's better to use `git for-each-ref` here, but the existing loop should work well enough for your purposes.)

But, then you run `git fetch --all`, which means *fetch from all remotes* (`fetch` defaults to fetching from the "current" remote, which is pretty loosely defined as "the current branch's remote, or `origin` if the current branch has no remote set).  Once the fetch finishes, you run `git pull --all`, which passes `--all` to `git fetch` again, then attempts to merge (or rebase) the current branch based on its configured `remote` and `merge` settings.

This therefore updates at most *one* of the branches you created in the `while` loop.

To merge-or-rebase each local branch, you need to loop over the local branches (again, preferably using `git for-each-ref`).

Comment: Thanks, that worked like a charm :) Great explanation also!