# bash alias not working(open git status output files as vim tab)

Tags: git, bash, vim, alias, git-status

I am trying to make this alias working:

```
alias ciao="vim -p `git status --short | awk '{print $2}'; git show --pretty="format:" --name-only`
```

Basically I would like to open every files, printed by `git status`, as vim tab.
The command works properly when I run it in the prompt directly but I cannot make an alias of it.

Looks like `vim -p` is applied to the first file printed but not to the others (when the files from `git status` are more than one).

I would love if somebody can tell me what I am doing wrong: in the alias I pasted there are obvious problems (like escaping), sorry about that.

Comment: As demonstrated in the accepted answer, you should always prefer `$(...)` rather than backticks for command substitutions.

Comment: the consequent question for me was "why", so here the answer I found, in case can be of interest for somebody else too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4708549/whats-the-difference-between-command-and-command-in-shell-programming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
alias ciao='vim -p $(
    git status --short | awk "{print $2}";
    git show --pretty="format:" --name-only
)'
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. I understand I was doing a mess with the quotes, feeling dumb :(

Answer (score 1):

Anything more complicated than `ls -l` should be a function, not an alias.

```
ciao () {
  vim -p $(git status --short | awk '{print $2}'
            git show --pretty="format:" --name-only)
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Vim opens up but no files are loaded

Comment: @lzzluca, Comments can be edited for 5 minutes.  Another option to multiple comments when they haven't been addressed yet is to just delete them and put all info into one comment.

Comment: One problem is that I quoted the command substitution, which passes a single argument to `vim`. That won't work here, since the output of the two `git` commands is clearly supposed to be multiple file names. You can unquote the command substitution, but be aware that this subjects the result to word-splitting and globbing, which means it may not work for all legal file names.