# Loop through filenames in bash

Tags: bash, for-loop

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Bash version ${BASH_VERSION}..."
for f in *.webm; do
  uuid=$(uuidgen)
  ffmpeg -i $f -vcodec libx264 -preset slow -crf 18 -vf scale=720:-2 ${uuid}.mp4
done
```

./convert.sh: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `$'do\r''
'/convert.sh: line 3:`for f in *.webm; do

I have many .webm files in a folder and I want to convert them all using ffmpeg!

The problem was about Windows. 
I was using Bash on Windows and it gave me issues.

Comment: file has carriage returns, remove them.

Comment: That was about the carriage returns. Thank you!

Answer (score -3):

Try:

```
...
for f in `ls *.webm`; do
...
done
```

Comment: `for f in *.webm` is _exactly_ how to do it. What you have suggested is a complete anti-pattern.

Comment: +1 @TomFenech you've mentioned somewhere that `[[ $(...) ]]` is also an anti pattern. Could you please point us a documentation or some-other reference with further details on bash anti-patterns.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4708549/2088135 explains why backticks are deprecated. `[[ $() ]]` isn't necessarily wrong but often comes from misunderstanding of how tests work in the shell. Search "shell anti-patterns" and you will find plenty of information. Also the [bash tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info) has a lot of useful links.