# Can't run utop after installation

Tags: ocaml, utop

I've just installed utop on openSUSE but when i type utop in terminal i have

```
If 'utop' is not a typo you can use command-not-found to lookup the package that contains it, like this:
cnf utop
```

Typing `eval 'opam config env'` gives me this:

```
OPAM_SWITCH_PREFIX='/home/jadw1/.opam/default'; export OPAM_SWITCH_PREFIX;
CAML_LD_LIBRARY_PATH='/home/jadw1/.opam/default/lib/stublibs:/usr/lib64/ocaml/stublibs:/usr/lib64/ocaml'; export CAML_LD_LIBRARY_PATH;
OCAML_TOPLEVEL_PATH='/home/jadw1/.opam/default/lib/toplevel'; export OCAML_TOPLEVEL_PATH;
MANPATH='/usr/local/man:/usr/share/man:/home/jadw1/.opam/default/man'; export MANPATH;
PATH='/home/jadw1/.opam/default/bin:/home/jadw1/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/lib/mit/sbin'; export PATH;
```

Answer (score 1):

You're supposed to type this:

```
$ eval `opam config env`
```

Not this:

```
$ opam config env
```

What happens is that `opam config env` writes out some shell commands that you want to execute. That's what the `eval` does. If you see output like you saw, it means you left out the `eval`.

Comment: But the question mentioned (albeit in a poorly formatted way) `eval 'opam config env'`. You might want to stress the fact that in shell, a backtick `\`` is **very** different from a single quote `'` (or [suggest to use `$()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4708569/1633665))

Comment: by the way, did u install utop : "opam install utop" ?

Answer (score 1):

`eval` is a command that constructs commands from the arguments it's given and executes them.

`eval 'opam config env'`, with apostrophes, is therefore equivalent to just running `opam config env` directly, which just writes out a sequence of shell commands.

If you replace the apostrophes with backticks, however, it will first execute the quoted command, then pass *its output* to `eval` and execute *that*.

```
eval `opam config env`
```

is therefore more or less equivalent to running `opam config env`, then copying and pasting the output back into the console, which you could also do.