# Git grep print only matching pattern

Tags: git, grep

In the manual for `grep`, we have `-o` to print `--only-matching` patterns.  Say `echo foobar | grep foo` would return `foobar`, but adding `-o` to `grep` would give only `foo`.

Many `grep` options like `-P`, `-c`, etc, can be used in conjunction with `git` to search through all files in the Git index.  However, `git grep -o PAT` triggers an `error: unknown switch`o'`.

How can I print only matched string for each file in the Git index? i.e. "`git grep -o PAT`"

My trial:

```
for f in `git ls-files`; do grep -o PAT $f; done
```

Comment: You should avoid using old and deprecated back-tics, use parentheses like this: `for f in $(git ls-files); do grep -o PAT $f; done` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4708549/what-is-the-difference-between-command-and-command-in-shell-programming

Comment: Another workaround I used: `git grep PAT | grep -o PAT`. It's sometimes less to type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[git grep 2.18](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-grep/2.18.0) doesn't have the option `-o|--only-matching`, [git grep 2.19](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-grep/2.19.0#git-grep--o) has. If your version is lower than 2.19 you cannot use the option. To use it you have to upgrade.