# How to Prefix Substrings in a Space-Delimited String in Shell Script

Tags: string, shell, portability

I have a space-delimited string of files that may or may not be prefixed with "/" (i.e. their paths are relative to a given root):

```
mydirs='a /b/c /d/e/f g /h/i'
```

I need to prefix each file with the root provided by the user. I need a portable way of doing this (It also goes without saying that I prefer speed, so builtins are welcome). So we're all on the same page, by "portable" I mean "portable across different linux shells (sh, bash, ksh, zsh, tsh, csh, etc.)"

Currently, my solution is:

```
root="my_root"  # User-supplied root directory

prefixed_dirs=`echo $mydirs |
tr ' ' '
' | sed 's;^/*;prefix/;' | tr '
' ' '`
```

which also puts a space at the end of my line, which isn't what I want.

My desired output would be the single line echoed back to me with the files prefixed, like so:

```
my_root/a my_root/b/c my_root/d/e/f my_root/g my_root/h/i
```

I've tried searching SO for answers, but I haven't really found what I'm looking for (please point me to a solution if there is one). I know sed operates on new lines by default, so I'm essentially trying to make sed operate on the beginning of substrings (I can't just look for spaces because it will skip `a` in the above).

This works, but the syntax is ugly. Is there a cleaner way to do this (again, while maintaining portability)? Perhaps a clean `awk` or `perl` one-liner (again, must be portable)? Double points for a clean sed one-liner!

Thanks a lot!

Comment: sh and csh are very different languages. I haven't used csh in many years, but I recall that even setting a variable has different syntax. Do you really _really_ need such extreme portability?

Comment: @glennjackman TBH, I haven't used csh or even tsh for that matter. By sh I mean dash. Honestly, if you have something that works well for sh, bash, ksh, and zsh (the usual suspects), I'd be a happy camper.

Comment: @glennjackman So I guess, no, to answer your question: I don't need that extreme of portability. My current code base tests against sh (i.e. dash), ash, bash, ksh, mksh, and zsh, if that helps.

Comment: This works in bash/ksh/zsh, but not dash: `prefixed_dirs="${root}/${mydirs// / $root/}"; prefixed_dirs=${prefixed_dirs//\/\///}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The single-line sed is

```sh
prefixed_dirs=$(echo "$mydirs" | sed -E "s, , $root/,g; s,^,$root/,; s,//,/,g")
```

Use `$(...)` instead of `` `...` `` -- see
https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2006
for more details.

Comment: Oh very nice! A "two-liner" (i.e. split by ";"). Well done! And you're correct regarding `\`...\``. The only reason I used them is because shellcheck.net seemed to indicate `$()` are not fully portable in some cases (POSIX != portable), but you're right: `$()` is the preferred syntax. Have you ever encountered that?

Comment: Correction, "3-liner" (add prefix to all entries separated with a space, then the entry at the beginning of the line, and lastly remove double "//"s).

Comment: In my experience, almost entirely on backend development, portability is not a priority: if I'm writing a shell script, it will run on a particular server in a particular OS with a particular shell. If you're writing scripts that you will distribute to users who will try to run them with who-knows-what shell, that's a different story.

Comment: If it fits in 80 characters, it's a one-liner no matter how many semicolons it has ;) -- I could have written `sed -E -e "s, , $root/,g" -e "s,^,$root/," -e "s,//,/,g"` with no semicolons.

Comment: True! It's for sure a 1-liner.

Comment: I was curious why my code base explicitly used backticks instead of `$()`, so I did some digging and found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4708549/what-is-the-difference-between-command-and-command-in-shell-programming. A user commented that for portability "it is recommended to use backticks for non-nested calls. $(...) needs a recursive parser but this was not used with ksh86 that introduced the feature." Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Name a shell you're using and/or coding for that is not POSIX-compliant

Comment: Probly just some older ash, mksh, and pdksh shells. Not really a big concern; just handling corner cases.

Comment: I just read your earlier comment regarding portability priority. That makes sense, and I think that's why backticks are in my code base: my code is qctually intended to be shared with others and it is uncertain as to which shell they might run. Thanks for your insight!

Answer (score 3):

You could use the `set` command to set the string constituents as positional arguments and then run a POSIX supported parameter expansion technique to remove the leading `/` if present.

Note that, using `set` on an unquoted variable expansion is also subject to glob expansion. Ensure that there is no scope for that to happen.

```sh
root="my_root"
mydirs='a /b/c /d/e/f g /h/i'

set -- $mydirs

for arg; do 
  printf '%s ' "${root}/${arg#/}"
done
```

Or if you anticipate glob expansion to happen, surround the set command with `set -f` and `set +f` to disable and enable glob expansion back.

Comment: `set -f` turns off globbing.

Comment: @Inian Very nice too! I like the readability (would ease maintenance). And you're right, I didn't need globbing off here, but it is definitely good to know!