# how to capture text after / but before 2nd - symbols in zsh

Tags: zsh

For example I have a git branch name `feature/ABC-123-my-stuff`

I want to just capture ABC-123 in this format.

I tried

```
cut -d "/" -f2 <<< "$branchName"
```

result in

```
ABC-123-my-stuff
```

but I want to only keep the string right after the `/` and before 2nd `-`

What do I add / modify to achieve that?

NOTE: I am using zsh on MacOS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `cut` 2 times:

```
(cut -d"/" -f2 | cut -d"-" -f1,2) <<< $branchName
```

or with `echo`:

```
echo $branchName | cut -d"/" -f2 | cut -d"-" -f1,2
```

Another way you can use `grep`:

```
echo $branchName | egrep -o '[A-Z]{3}-[0-9]{3}'
```

Note: this solution will work if you have every time 3 times capital letter, then `-`, then 3 digits.

All solutions gives me the output:

```
ABC-123
```

Comment: How can I store the first approach into a var? I tried
ticketName=(cut -d"/" -f2 | cut -d"-" -f1,2) <<< $branchName;
`syntax error near unexpected token `|'`

But it gave me error of

Comment: @Ezeewei, `var=$((cut -d"/" -f2 | cut -d"-" -f1,2) <<< $branchName)`

Comment: I am noobie, why we need that `$()`?

Comment: If you want to put the output of commands in a variable you have to use `$()` or \`\`. This is an element of Bash syntax. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4708549/what-is-the-difference-between-command-and-command-in-shell-programming) you can find professional explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Use regexp matching:

```
 if [[ $branchName =~ /([^-]+-[^-]+)- ]]
 then
   desired_part=$match[1]
 else
   echo $branchName has not the expected format
 fi
```

Comment: I got syntax error.... I tried to use this in VS Code terminal in Mac

Comment: Which zsh-Version are you using? Mine is 5.8. Also, plesae copy and paste the full error message you got.

Comment: ```

./test2.sh: line 20: syntax error near unexpected token `else'
./test2.sh: line 20: ` else'


```

Comment: Copy and paste error of my part. Updated. Aside from this: Your error message sounds odd. I would have expected that you have gotten _zsh: parse error near `else'_. You didn't mention yet your zsh version.

Comment: Now the result is only `[1]`

Comment: btw I have zsh 5.7.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin19.0)

Comment: See the screenshot [here](https://postimg.cc/WFrr3Mkq). AFIK, I'm not using any feature which was introduced in 5.8. Could you also contribute a screenshot from your side?

Comment: it looks Windows OS.... I am not sure if the zsh on win is the same as zsh Mac? as the chosen answer worked and I do not yet know why your answer is not working for me... but thanks for contributing! and I like the approach to add IF ELSE to avoid error

Comment: It is cygwin inside Windows, but the zsh is built from the same sources. There are certainly no differences in the way regular expressions are calculated. I would need to see a trace (`set -x`) from your side, to comment what is going on there. So far you didn't even post a screenshot, sadly .... If I were you, I would investigate this, because I would feel uncomfortable if my shell somehow behaves differently from what it is supposed to.