# Unable to set Variable in gitlab-ci.yml

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, zsh, cicd

In this abridged version of a gitlab-ci.yaml file. The global variable APP_VERSION can either be filled or left blank. In the case of it being left blank, I want to set the variable to the version value that exists in *version_cache/version.txt*. If APP_VERSION already contains a version, then it will use that.

```
variable:
  APP_VERSION: ""

build_image:
  stage: build_image
  before_script:
    - APP_VERSION=if [ -z $APP_VERSION ]; then echo $(cat version_cache/version.txt); else echo $APP_VERSION; fi;
```

When the runner runs this, I get

```
bash: eval: line 128: syntax error near unexpected token `then'
```

The runner uses zsh. I saw an example on SO where a variable is set this way, yet I'm unable to understand the missing syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue seems to be that you are trying to assign a value to `APP_VERSION`, but you are passing the actual code, `not` the result as you intend to. Add **``** to explain to bash that you need the result of the command. As an addition to VonC's answer

Try changing

```
- APP_VERSION=if [ -z $APP_VERSION ]; then echo $(cat version_cache/version.txt); else echo $APP_VERSION; fi;
```

To

```
- APP_VERSION=`if [ -z "$APP_VERSION" ]; then cat version_cache/version.txt; else echo "$APP_VERSION"; fi;`
```

Answer (score 1):

After checking with [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/), try:

```
$(if [ -z "$APP_VERSION" ]; then cat version_cache/version.txt; else echo "$APP_VERSION"; fi;)
```

Comment: Still getting error: $ APP_VERSION=if [ -z "$APP_VERSION" ]; then cat version_cache/version.txt; else echo "$APP_VERSION"; fi;
bash: eval: line 128: syntax error near unexpected token `then'

Comment: @paiego Can you try and simplify, just for testing: `if [  "${APP_VERSION}" == "" ]; then...`

Comment: thanks for the help but I got it working with the Tolis' recommendation.

Comment: FYI: I was also able to get it working with $(), which is supposed to replace the back ticks '`' eventually: APP_VERSION=$(if [ -z "$APP_VERSION" ]; then cat version_cache/chart_version.txt; else echo "$APP_VERSION"; fi;)

Comment: @paiego Good call: I already documented the [difference between `$(command)` and ```command``` in shell programming](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24592916/6309) seven years ago.