# git keyword substitution under windows using gnutools (gnuwin32)

Tags: windows, git, sed, smartgit

I just converted my SVN repository to git. For the management I use keyword-substitution.
Excerpt from the git config

```
smudge = "set author=`git log --pretty=format:%ae -1`; SET last_date=`git log --pretty=format:\"%ai\" -1`; SET version=`echo $lastdate | cut -d \" \" -f 1-2 | sed -e \"s/[ -:]/./g\"`; sed -e \"s/[$]Revision[$]/\\$Revision: $last_date \$/\" -e \"s/[$]Date[$]/\\$Date: $last_date \$/\" -e \"s/[$]Author[$]/\\$Author: $author \\$/\" "
clean = sed -r -e 's/([$]Revision|Date|Author)(:[^$]+ [$])/\\1$/'
```

Source: https://github.com/np-trivial/git-keyword-substitution

This solution should in principle also run under Windows, since I also use gnuwin32. Tools are accessible in the system environment variable.
Unfortunately I always get an error message. As far as I could isolate it is because of the above code.
I just have no idea what the problem is.

Comment: Always show the exact errors (cut and paste text if at all possible): see [ask]. It seems odd that you use `set` and then `SET`: if this is a bash or sh style command, you don't want either of those, just `author=$(...)` or ```author=`...` ...``` for instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need gnuwin32.
Content filter driver would work from a regular CMD session, and would be executed with the git bash included with Git for Windows.

That means your smudge/clean scripts should be in bash.
`set xx=` is a BAT assignmemnt. `xx=...` is a bash assignment.

Try:

```bash
smudge = "author=$(git log --pretty=format:%ae -1); last_date=$(git log --pretty=format:\"%ai\" -1); version=$(echo $lastdate | cut -d \" \" -f 1-2 | sed -e \"s/[ -:]/./g\"); sed -e \"s/[$]Revision[$]/\\$Revision: $last_date \$/\" -e \"s/[$]Date[$]/\\$Date: $last_date \$/\" -e \"s/[$]Author[$]/\\$Author: $author \\$/\" "
clean = sed -r -e 's/([$]Revision|Date|Author)(:[^$]+ [$])/\\1$/'
```

In other words, remove the `set`.

However, the [OP ozz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/648597/ozz) confirms in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73843264/git-keyword-substitution-under-windows-using-gnutools-gnuwin32/73843758?noredirect=1#comment130394710_73843758) that SmartGit does not support content filter driver.

A simple `git checkout` or `git switch` does triggers it (successfully) in command-line though.

Comment: SmartGit still complains " Can not run program "author=`git.. CreateProcess Error 2. File not found"

Comment: @ozz First, [replace backtick with `$(...)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24592916/6309). Second, debug by simplifying your smudge. Try with just `author=$(git log --pretty=format:%ae -1)`, to check if it runs. Then add other directives to your smudge, to pinpoint the issue.

Comment: @ozz Test it outside of SmartGit, with kust Git for Windows, in a CMD, using `git switch anotherBranch`: a switch to branch triggers the smudge.

Comment: it seems to be a problem with smartgit. via "git checkout <file>" it works now. Thanks you

Comment: @ozz Great, well done! I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.