# why variable substitution is so different?

Tags: bash, shell

there are two files in current dir

```
[root@workspace tmp]# ll
total 8
-rw-------. 1 root root 6 Mar 31 13:18 *
-rw-------. 1 root root 6 Mar 31 13:18 ?

[root@workspace tmp]# for f in "`find . -type f`";do echo "$f";done
./*
./?

[root@workspace tmp]# for f in "`find . -type f`";do echo $f;done
./* ./? ./* ./?
```

I am confused about the output of the two echo ...

the differenct is: the double quote around the $f

why the outputs are so, anyone can explain this?

thanx any help in advance.

Comment: Please read https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001#Input_source_selection, https://stackoverflow.com/q/4708549/1745001, https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes and, as the [tag:bash] tag you used instructs, always copy/paste your code into http://shellcheck.net before posting a question as it'll detect and explain some of the issues in your code.

Comment: See [Bash Pitfalls #1 (for f in $(ls *.mp3))](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shell *expands* the commands before executing them. There are 7 consecutive expansions: brace expansion, tilde expansion, parameter and variable expansion, command substitution, arithmetic expansion, word splitting, and pathname expansion (see [this section of the bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Expansions.html)).

In your case brace expansion, tilde expansion and arithmetic expansion have no effect because you do not use these features.

Before the `for` loop is executed command substitution replaces the `find` command with `./? ./*`. Because it is enclosed in double quotes the word splitting does not split `./? ./*` and filename expansion is skipped. The `for` command is thus not further transformed before execution. The loop iterates only once with value `./? ./*` of variable `f`.

In `echo "$f"` `$f` is expanded (parameter expansion) and replaced with the value of variable `f`. Again, because of the double quotes, word splitting and filename expansion are skipped, the result is printed without further modifications, and you see `./? ./*`.

In `echo $f`, `$f` is also expanded and replaced with the value of `f` but the expansion continues with word splitting and pathname expansion. Word splitting separates the two words `./?` and `./*` such that they are treated separately in the next steps. Pathname expansion replaces `./?` with the list of all single-character file names in current directory (in your case `./?` and `./*`) and `./*` is replaced with the list of all file names in current directory (in your case `./?` and `./*`). So, finally what is echoed is `./? ./* ./? ./*`.

Comment: thanx very much, but why the output of the echo $f  is just one line?
shouldn't be 2 lines?

Comment: Because there is only one iteration of the loop, with `f=./? ./*`. So `echo` is executed only once with `"./? ./*"` or `./? ./*`. If you remove the double quotes around the `find` command the command substitution and the pathname expansions will replace it with `./? ./* ./? ./*`, there will be 4 iterations and 4 `echo`. You will see 4 lines with either 1 token each (`echo "$f"`) or 2 tokens each (`echo $f`).