# How does python work with outside pipe and sys.stdin

Tags: python, linux, pipe

In a Linux sandbox, I tried to run a python3 script from network by piping `python3`. And the script also reads data from `sys.stdin`.

It was a little bit like :

```py
echo 'import sys ; print(f"python here {sys.stdin.read()}")' | python3 <<here
data here
here
```

in posix shell `sh`. And it told me :

```
$ echo 'import sys ; print(f"python here {sys.stdin.read()}")' | python3 <<here
> data here
> here
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    data here
         ^^^^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

It seems that the here document `data here` was read by `python3` itself but not the python script process.

Is there any possible way to contact with the internal `sys.stdin`? Or what will be valid to replace it? In a sandbox maybe I can't use a regular file.

Comment: Does [python -c vs python -<< heredoc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30702519/) answer your question?

Comment: @U880D Yes it is. Something like `echo data here | python3 -c "$(echo 'import sys ; print(f"python here {sys.stdin.read()}")')"` works. Thanks!