# How to use a different file-descriptor in a shell pipeline?

Tags: bash, unix, sh, pipeline, file-descriptor

I'm dealing with a script, that invokes a noisy (lots of diagnostics on both `stdout` and `stderr`) program first, and then processes its output with other tools.

The program's verbosity makes it impossible to simply send its stdout to pipeline, so currently we use a *temporary file* -- a practice I'd like to end.

Instead of `/tmp/foo`, we can ask the program to write the data to `/dev/fd/N` -- and it will, no problem (it does not need to `seek` the file, for example).

What noise it currently sends to `stdout` and `stderr`, can continue going there -- the operators are used to seeing it, and will be alarmed, if it disappears...

But how do I arrange for the descriptor `N` to exist and be sent into the next program's `stdin`?

```sh
noisy -o /dev/fd/N ?????| filter -i /dev/stdin
```

If this requires `bash`, so be it, but I'd prefer a solution suitable for the entire sh-family, of course.

Comment: I think you should keep using a temporary file.

Comment: Temporary files are bad. They are less efficient, and they litter the filesystems -- code required to reliably clean them is uglier than any answer to my question will be. They may be used by someone _in a hurry_ -- too busy to do things _right_. But to encourage their use, as you do, is even more wrong than using them.

Comment: Well, good luck then

Comment: Could you use a named pipe, as in [Example of using named pipes in Linux Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4113986/example-of-using-named-pipes-in-linux-bash)?

Comment: A more fruitful approach might be to write a wrapper which suppresses the noise and only keeps the useful output. If the noise is predictable, it could be as simple as a single `grep`.

Comment: @ShaneBishop, though named pipes don't have the efficiency problem of temporary files, they are still littering the filesystems. I've accept the answer by pjh with gratitude -- everyone should understand it to make their shell scripts better.

Comment: Temporary files are sometimes the best option, and sometimes unavoidable.  See [Removing created temp files in unexpected bash exit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/687014) for clean, reliable, and safe ways to create them and ensure that they are cleaned up (`mktemp`, `trap ... EXIT`).  Programs that use temporary files can also be easier to debug because intermediate results can be examined.

Comment: @pjh, `trap` will not help, if an impatient operator kills your script with `kill -9`. Nor is `trap` any better-looking, than the mechanism you provided in your answer -- while the inefficiency is still there. Kernel does not know, your file is temporary -- it still has to sync the data to filesystem. The only valid observation is ease of debugging -- but for that one can simply insert `tee /tmp/temp` in front of the `| filter`. _Temporarily_ -- to be removed, when the debugging is over.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, you've got a program that writes noise to standard output and standard error, and writes useful data to a file specified with a `-o` option.  You want standard output and standard error to be left as they are, but pipe the useful data into a filter program instead of writing it to file.

The easiest way to do that with Bash is to use process substitution (see [ProcessSubstitution - Greg's Wiki](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution)):

```
noisy -o >(filter -i /dev/stdin)
```

Note that process substitution is not available in some sh-family shells, it is not available with Bash on some (uncommon) platforms, and there is no way to get the exit status of a process created with process substitution with Bash before version 4.4.

Another possible way to do what (I think) you want is:

```
exec 3>&1
{ exec 4>&1; noisy -o /dev/fd/4 >&3 ; } | filter -i /dev/stdin
```

- `exec 3>&1` makes file descriptor 3 refer to the "real" standard output.
- `exec 4>&1` (since it is run in a process that is the first stage of a pipeline) makes file descriptor 4 refer to the input to the next stage in the pipeline.
- `noisy ... >&3` forces the standard output of `noisy` to go to the "real" standard output.
- Writing to `/dev/fd/4` (on Linux at least) writes to the next stage in the pipeline.

I've only tested it with Bash, but I think it should work with other sh-family shells.

Comment: Thanks for the solution! Honestly, I don't understand, how to make my question any clearer -- but I'm glad, you got it :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is one possible way:

```bash
( \
  /my/noisy/script \
    2> >(tee /tmp/stderr.log) \
    1> >(tee /tmp/stdout.log) \
) 2>&1 | tee /tmp/both.log
```

Replace the `tee` calls with whatever filter you like.